# Google Maps MarkerClusterer v3 Return Cluster of Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am currently using the Google Maps MarkerClusterer v3 (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) and have been very impressed with the functionality so far.

However, I now wish to add in an additional function to my map. When a user hovers over a list of the markers, the marker image is changed. This works great when the markers aren't clustered, but since I am also using the Clusterer, I need to be able to return the Cluster to which a specific marker belongs.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I checked the API documents, but couldn't find a method to return an array of the Clusters.

Essentially, here is a pseudo-code of what I need to do:

```
function changeClusterIcon(the_marker)
{
    var clusters = _CLUSTERER.getClusters();
    var clusters_length = clusters.length;
    var marker_pos = the_marker.getPosition().toString();

    for(var i = 0; i < clusters_length; i++)
    {
        var this_cluster = clusters[i];
        var the_markers = this_cluster.markers.length;

        for(var j = 0; j < the_markers; j++) 
        {
            var this_marker = this_cluster.markers[i];
            if(this_marker.getPosition().toString() == marker_pos)
            {
                return this_cluster;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MarkerClusterer` library does not provide a way to retrieve the clusters. But there is an enhanced version of the library, [MarkerClustererPlus](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries#MarkerClustererPlus), which provides more capabilities. Using MarkerClustererPlus[<sup>api-doc</sup>](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.9/docs/reference.html), you may use the `MarkerClusterer.getClusters()` function to retrieve an `Array` of the `Cluster` class instances. Then, you may use the `Cluster.getMarkers()` function to retrieve an `Array` of the markers that are within that `Cluster`. And with that, you should have what you need to move forward.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to construct a helper function in the original `MarkerClusterer` library which returns an array of the clusters that it has created. Essentially, the library **does** store the clusters, it just doesn't provide a native function to access them. I'll accept your answer though, as I was able to get around the issue by studying the code of the Plus library.

Comment: Yep, the `MarkerClusterer` absolutely holds the clusters; I've been through that code myself. I was trying to convey that with the "does not provide a way to retrieve the clusters" wording, but I guess it wasn't entirely clear. At any rate, it helped you move forward, which is the most important part. Glad it's working for you -

Answer (score 0):

Your function is almost correct, here the proper version:

```
function changeClusterIcon(the_marker)
{
var clusters = _CLUSTERER.getClusters();
var clusters_length = clusters.length;
var marker_pos = the_marker.getPosition().toString();

for(var i = 0; i < clusters_length; i++)
{
    var this_cluster = clusters[i];
    var the_markers = this_cluster.markers_.length;

    for(var j = 0; j < the_markers; j++) 
    {
        var this_marker = this_cluster.markers_[j];
        if(this_marker.getPosition().toString() == marker_pos)
        {
            return this_cluster;
        }
    }
}

return false;
}
```

So the **markers** property should be called as **markers_** and the second foreach uses **j** instead of **i**.